# Server Sizing to run Landscape Management

Tags: server, landscape

Anyone know where I can find information to properly size our servers for [Landscape](https://landscape.canonical.com/)?  We created a [POC server](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/the-ims-ip/9780470019061/9780470019061_poc_architecture.html) and now plan to move forward but need more information than just the minimum sizing requirements that Canonical provides.

Comment: Please confirm you wish to use Landscape On-Premises https://docs.ubuntu.com/landscape/en/onprem as the other two configurations will have differing requirements. To do so, please click [edit] and add that specification to your original question, instead of using Add Comment. Why?  Comments accumulate, and new comments can push old comments offscreen.

Comment: Also, were you referring to the Ubuntu Server system requirements of r the Landscape System Requirements at https://landscape.canonical.com/static/doc/user-guide/ch03.html ?